# Why is the Eclipse JSP editor uncapable of double-click selecting in a reasonable manner?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I'd like to double click 'user' in this string

```
<h:outputText value="#{req.user}">
```

and then only "user" should be selected, as it's the only behaviour which makes sense in a Java environment, but (stupid) Eclipse selects the whole string between the quotes.

This is still present in Eclipes Helios.

Maybe I'm missing out something but I didn't find a setting which allows to change that behaviour.

Grateful for any hints or just whining about this missing feature (or rather bug) ...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Was the first sentence the example?  Are you trying to select it in an attribute value?

Comment: formatting was wrong - it's fixed now, thanks for the heads-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's that way because the JSP Editor is using the XML strategy for handling double-click (a lot of code is shared from the XML Editor), and no one has ever requested it work otherwise in Bugzilla.